# Asymptotic expansion

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

How to find the leading behaviour of $$\int_0^1\sqrt {p(1-p)} (p+a)^{-x} dp $$
To proceed with Laplace method, I substituted $(p+a)^{-x}$ as $e^{-x\ln(p+a)}$ Please help me to proceed. Is it right to Taylor expand the logarithmic term and approximate it?

Comment: Did you try $p=\sin^2(x)$. i havent tried but just thought of it as we may get rid of root.

Comment: Assuming $a > 0$, $\ln(p+a)$ is increasing in $p$ for $0 \leq p \leq 1$, so its minimum occurs at $p=0$. Replace $\ln(p+a)$ by $\ln(a) + p/a$ (the first two terms of its Maclaurin series) and $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ by $\sqrt{p}$ (its leading-order approximation near $p=0$) and $\int_0^1$ by $\int_0^\infty$ to get the leading order behavior of the integral as $x \to \infty$. Each of these steps can be rigorously justified by following the steps of the Laplace method.